# Как задать значение для переменной типа string от пользователя

Tags: c#, строки

Как в C# можно задать значение для string, что бы пользователь при работе с программой ввел к примеру свое имя в эту переменную.
В С++ у меня получалось так.

```
string name;
getline(std::cin, name);
cout << name;
```

В С# все иначе как я понимаю.
Пробовал вот так:

```
string name;
name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write(name);
```

и так

```
string name;
Console.ReadLine(name);
Console.Write(name);
```

Ничего не получается. На MSDN примеры все указаны с учетом того, что я заранее уже что то записал в строку. Как тогда в С# работать с словами? Мне элементарно надо в программе, что бы пользователь ввел свое имя по запросу и потом уже вывести приветствие и имя.

Comment: "Ничего не получается." - что это значит? Маленький гномик вылезает из компьютера и говорит: "Ничего не получается."?

Comment: Не компилируется элементарно:)

Comment: @Petr, должно компилироваться в варианте с лишним Convert'ом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция ReadLine считывает строку с консоли и возвращает ее пользователю функции.

Поэтому достаточно написать, например,

```
string name;
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine( name );
```

Answer (score 1):

метод `Console.ReadLine()` не принимает аргументов. Он возвращает строку, считанную с консоли после нажатия клавиши Enter:

`string name = Console.ReadLine();`